# Passing a textbox to a method. When using a textchanged event. C# visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, textbox, arguments, visual-studio-2013

I have a text box on my form which I am trying to add some validation to. I've attached the following method to the textchanged event. However I'm getting a 'no overload for method matches system.EventHandler' error. I don't really understand why I'm getting it. Am I not passing the arguments to the method when I call it?

```
        private void rangeValidate(TextBox textbox)
        {

            int mark = Convert.ToInt32(textbox.Text);
            if (mark >= 0 & mark >= 100)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number betwen 0 and 100");
            }

        }
```

Comment: To only allow marks between 0 and 100 you should have "mark >= 0 && mark <= 100"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you attached this method:

```
private void rangeValidate(TextBox textbox)
```

to `TextChanged`, you need to conform to the delegates signature. So, change it like this:

```
private void rangeValidate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textbox = sender as TextBox;
    int mark = Convert.ToInt32(textbox.Text);
    if (mark >= 0 & mark >= 100)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number betwen 0 and 100");
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP's main problem is a fundamental misunderstanding of what delegates are, how they work, and how they relate to events. A good explanation of this can be found [here](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/writing/delegates.htm). The article also addresses more advanced topics such as asynchronous event firing. I'd recommend not worrying about that for now and just trying to understand the first half of the article. You can read more details in this [C# in Depth Article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also declare this function like:

```
protected void rangeValidate(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

and add event in the pageload for the textbox, say TextBox1 as

```
TextBox1.TextChanged += rangeValidate;
```